# Login with Facebook Js SDK - AJAX not working

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, facebook, authentication

i have a login page that i want to allow users to login via facebook. The flow is simple. The user (already registered in my app) and logged in in my app, clicks in a fb button and by doing so it will redirect to fb. If the fb login is successfull i save the facebook id of that user on my database in a field. 
For this above it seems to work, but then i tried a small test, which was while logged out in our app but logged in fb i tried to access my db and get the user's info based on the id already saved, but for some reason the ajax part is not working, i expected to see the var_dump i have on my facebook.php

This is my login.php

```
<body>    
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Enviar">                  
                    <button class="btn btn-social-icon btn-facebook" id="facebook" onclick="login(); return false;"><span class="fa fa-facebook"></span></button>
                    <div id="status"></div> 

                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <a href="#">Recuperar password ...</a>
                </div>

            </form>
        </div>
        <script>


  var id;
    // initialize and set up facebook javascript sdk
    window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
      FB.init({
        appId      : '***************',
        cookie     : true,
        xfbml      : true,        
        version    : 'v2.11'
      });

      FB.getLoginStatus(function(response){

        if(response.status === "connected"){
          document.getElementById("status").innerHTML="Okay you are connected";
          info(); 
        }else if(response.status==="not_authorized"){
          document.getElementById("status").innerHTML="You are not connected.";
        }else{
          document.getElementById("status").innerHTML="You are not logged in facebook account.";
        }
      });

      FB.AppEvents.logPageView();  


      };

    (function(d, s, id){
      var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
      if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
      js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
      js.src = "https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
      fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

    function login(){

      FB.login(function(response){        
        //console.log("entrou aqui");
        if(response.status === "connected"){
          document.getElementById("status").innerHTML="Okay you are connected";
          info();
        }else if(response.status==="not_authorized"){
          document.getElementById("status").innerHTML="You are not connected.";
        }else{
          document.getElementById("status").innerHTML="You are not logged in facebook account.";
        }
      });
    }

    function info(){

       FB.api('/me','GET',{fields: 'name, email, id'}, function(response){
          //document.getElementById('status').innerHTML=response.id;
            id = response.id;            
            $.ajax({
              url: 'facebook.php?facebook_operation=0&response_id='+id,
              type: 'GET',                  
              success:function(data){
                console.log("sucesso??");

              }
            });                       
       });      
    }

  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

And this is my facebook.php

```
<?php  
    session_start();
    include "config.php";

    if(isset($_GET['facebook_operation'])){

        if($_GET['facebook_operation']==1){
            try {
                $sql = "UPDATE pessoa SET 
                        facebook_id=:facebook_id WHERE idpessoa=".$_SESSION['idpessoa'];

                $result = $conPdo->prepare($sql);

                $result->bindParam(':facebook_id', $param_facebook, PDO::PARAM_STR);

                $param_facebook = $_GET['response_id'];

                $result->execute();

            } catch (PDOException $e) {
                die($e->getMessage());
            }

        }else{

            try {
                $sql_fb = "SELECT * FROM pessoa WHERE facebook_id=".$_GET['response_id'];

                $resultado = $conPdo->query($sql_fb);   

                if($resultado->rowCount()==1){
                    $row_fb = $resultado->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
                }
                var_dump($row_fb);
                exit;
            } catch (PDOException $e) {
                die($e->getMessage());
            }
        }
    }

?>
```

Comment: is this condition `if($resultado->rowCount()==1){` satisfied?

Comment: no. It isn't, but there exists the user i am testing in my db with the fb id in there. i checked in phppgadmin. for me it seems it is not even doing the $_GET in the ajax code

Comment: it prints the console.log in the ajax code though.